COM Exception when running multiple MS tests
I am getting below COM Exception when running more than one test case at a time.
"Create an instance of a component with CLSID COM's {} from IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80004005 Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))"
Same test cases are passing if run individually.
As it is working for individual acceptance tests seems there is no setup/configuration or permission issue.
I am calling FoxPro dll in C#.
Code Sample:
public class TestWrapper : IDisposable 
{

~TestWrapper()
{ 
  Dispose();
}

private ibsitest;
Public TestWrapper()
{
    poTest = new ibsitest();
}

Protected virtual void Dispose()
{
   If(poTest != null)
   {
         poTest.close();
        poTest = null;
   }
}
}


The class factory is implemented by the COM component you're calling. The error you get just means this COM component has a problem. Maybe it doesn't like the way you call it (but it should report another error), but we can't help you more here, you should contact whoever developped it.

Does your FoxPro COM Component state that its able to run in a multithreaded environment? Or did you mean something else then in parallel with "more then one test case at a time"?

You might need to specify [STAThread] on your void Main function, if the component only allows an STA apartment, rather than free threading or MTA.

Do you know against which runtime the COM server was compiled, VFP9T.DLL or VFP9R.DLL? Both runtimes only support STA apartments. VFP9R.DLL doesn't support multiple instances.
